Azure Logic App : retrieve a value from key value within parsed JSON
I am building a logic app where I have some JSON pulled from Shopify this has extended properties like this
{
  "metafields": [
    {
      "id": 222222,
      "namespace": "global",
      "key": "test",
      "value": "210690"      
    },
    {
      "id": 555555,
      "namespace": "custom",
      "key": "pallet_quantity",
      "value": 2      
    }
  ]
}

I can use an expression like this:
body('Parse_VariantMetaJSON')?['metafields'][0]['value'] 

to get me the value of the object with a name of test however from my testing it is not always 0 and if its empty and a different field is populated that becomes 0.
Can I target this with an expression that identifies using the value of key? I have tried this
first(body('Parse_VariantMetaJSON')?['metafields'][?(@['key'] == 'test')])?['value']

But the logic app always states that it is an invalid expression.

I think the simplest way would be to use the Filter array operation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#filter-array-action
It’s by far the easiest way to target the item you are wanting to retrieve.
It will make your flow a little more verbose but it does the job.

Use Javascript Code to extract this value. Add Inline Code action named Execute JavaScript Code and add following code. You can use the output of this action later and it would contain the value e.g. 210690 in the sample given above.
function getFirstValueByKey(parsedJsonObj, key) {
  let metafieldsWithKeyAsTest = parsedJsonObj.metafields.filter((mf) => mf.key == key);

  return metafieldsWithKeyAsTest.length > 0 ? metafieldsWithKeyAsTest[0].value : null;
}

let parsedJsonObj = workflowContext.actions.Parse_VariantMetaJSON.outputs.body

var firstValue = getFirstValueByKey(parsedJsonObj, "test");

console.log(firstValue);

return firstValue;

